# Kestrel SSL Problem in a Server with No Internet Access

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

## TL;DR

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Self-signed Certificate + Server connected to the Internet = Successful responses

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Self-signed Certificate + With Proxy = Successful responses

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Self-signed Certificate + No Internet = Successful responses

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Trusted Authority Signed Certificate + Server connected to the Internet = Successful responses

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Trusted Authority Signed Certificate + With Proxy = Successful responses

ASP.NET App + Kestrel + Trusted Authority Signed Certificate + No Internet = Failed responses  (How can I fix this?)

## Long Version:

We are trying to run a ASP.NET Core project with SSL support in a Docker container. We generated a certificate signed by a trusted authority. The certificate is fine. We can run the application in a server having internet access.

The problem is this: When we try to run this application in a server with no internet access, the requests we make to this application give timeouts (after 20 seconds approximately). Moreover, there is no ASP.NET log in this situation.

We have an internal proxy server to connect to internet. When we set http_proxy and https_proxy environment values in Docker container with this proxy, our application works just fine.

We gave this another try with a self-signed certificate, and the result is again success: We can make requests and get responses from our application just fine with a self-signed certificate.

I guess Kestrel looks something through the Internet with a trusted authority certificate. So, my questions are these:

1. What does Kestrel looks for through the Internet exactly?
2. How can I force Kestrel to require no Internet connection? I mean how can we run our application without using our proxy server and also without a direct Internet connection?

Comment: looking for root certs?

Comment: I guess it should be something related to CA validation